# Visual Studio 2015 Build Time for Small Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

There are many questions on SO about improving the build time in Visual Studio (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251212/how-to-improve-visual-c-compilation-times), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539347/what-are-ways-of-improving-build-compile-time), etc.), but the vast majority of answers are aimed at projects which are fairly large. Many of these answers (e.g. increasing amount of parallel builds) will only have a marginal effect on small projects, which is what motivates this question.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2015 with one solution, a single C++ project, containing only three files: an 800-line source file, and two .h files. I am running on Windows 7, my processor is Intel Core i5, CPU 2.60GHz, RAM 8GB.

**My build time is a staggering 1 minute or more.**

Based on suggestions in other SO threads, I have emptied my %temp% and prefetch directories, but this only had a marginal effect. I changed my code to remove as many warnings as possible. I removed all the unnecessary files from the VS directories for my project. My antivirus is disabled.

[Here](http://ardalis.com/speed-up-visual-studio-build-times) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199356/speed-up-compile-time-with-ssd) it was suggested that an SSD could help. I find it hard to believe, however, that my performance should be this poor with HDD.

I would be glad to hear any suggestions about this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You understand it's impossible to even evaluate this question without code, right?

Comment: I would open task manager during the compile. See if even 1 core is at 100% CPU usage. Also look at the disk usage.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis My question is about the IDE, not my code. I cannot think of which parts of my code you would want to see--I obviously cannot post 800+ lines. The related questions which I linked do not include any code, so it didn't occur to me that my question should be a special case. I am simply asking for best practices to reduce build time.

Comment: @drescherjm Good point. It uses 25%, any thoughts?

Comment: ***Good point. It uses 25%, any thoughts?*** I expect that means 1 core of your quad core is 100% loaded. If this is the case the problem is not related to your hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things you can do (not all may be relevant to your code):

Remove unneeded includes.

Build without optimization except for when doing release builds.

Use extern templates where possible.

Split your code into multiple source files so that only a subset of it needs recompilation when you make changes.

Use precompiled headers.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on building without optimization?

Comment: Building without optimization is the default for "Debug builds" in Visual Studio unless you've manually added options like `/O2` or similar.